# Unable to ask a question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I don't know how but I am not able to ask a question. It shows that we **are no longer accepting questions from this account**. What should I have to do so that I can again ask my questions in forum??

Comment: If I remember correctly, this happens of the sum of the votes on your questions goes negative past a certain threshold. You also have a few closed questions, but I'm not sure how they affect the issue.

Comment: @AndrejaKo So how can I get rid of this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could wait for one of the moderators to wake up and hope that they will have an explanation for this. One thing that could be useful is to try to analyze why the down-voted questions got their down-votes and try to avoid similar situations in future.

Comment: @AndrejaKo As a newbie I got lot's of downvotes. May be it was just because I don't know how to ask a good question or my questions doesn't seems any research effort?

Comment: Exactly. At this point, allowing you to ask more questions doesn't make sense. You need to step back and learn how to ask questions properly. Note that this has nothing to do with your level of electronics, but *how* you ask the questions. I just looked at your question history, and I agree that you have abused your priveledge here. Don't just blurt out more questions without learning why your previous questions were downvoted and closed.

Comment: @OlinLathrop So could you please suggest me what can I do. I understand that I asks in wrong way but as a newbie I don't know about the forum rule. Now I know what and how to ask a question. But what next as I am already in trouble. How can I get a upvotes on the questions that I asked

Comment: Read the FAQ.  There is no excuse for not knowing the rules.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I already did it. But I don't know what should I have to do to. Is there any way as there are two questions(as a newbie I want to ask my query) on which I got lots of downvotes. But I also got my answer. Are moderators have some priviledge to delete that question as I don't think that editing a closed question make a sense of others.

Answer (score 5):

The following post on Meta.SO post contains the official list of recommendations:

[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

I strongly suspect in your case the reason wasn't a couple of "average" questions, it was the answers you posted that contained plagiarism and copied content without proper attribution. There was one answer I recall that had close to 10 downvotes before it was deleted (possibly by a moderator). If you read the above link those deleted answers still count against you.

On that answer you had multiple comments that you should attribute the source of the answer, which you decided not to heed. Not only did you not edit that post, you went ahead and did the same on another answer that now only contains attribution because someone else edited it after you failed to do so:

[Formation of Ions in diode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81997/formation-of-ions-in-diode/81998#81998)

The [Creative Commons Attribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License) license used by Wikipedia requires that. When you don't do it apart from not sitting well with other members it also has possible legal implications.

As for your current situation I can't view your deleted questions and answers but maybe you could try to improve some of your existing questions. For example the following question might have a bit more promise and possibly be re-opened if you gave a few examples of specific circuits where you'd seen the use of a MOSFET for power control and wondered why they would be chosen over an SCR:

[Application of SCR & TRIAC in electronics Field](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73587/application-of-scr-in-electronics-field)

And otherwise just go through your questions and answers and see if there's any way they can be improved and you'll possibly pick up a vote or two. But if you do get your post privilege back please don't go cutting & pasting material from anywhere into answers else without stating the source it came from! That, along with ignoring constructive comments on your posts seems to have led to this situation in the first place.

Edited to add that W5VO has pointed out in a comment that question bans are separate from answer bans. So it appears in this case you should be concentrating on improving questions but keep in mind the same could apply in the future to answers if too many are downvoted for similar reasons.

Comment: How can I get or edit a question which is already closed.If you are talking about my question "Application of SCR in electronics Field", I got the answer but as I already got a lots of downvotes, what should I did to neutralize it. As a newbie (at that time) I just heard these in my books so I just want to ask their application.

Comment: @Atom, that question started very broadly and now I think further it may be hard to make it more generic without changing the context too much. Maybe ask for specific applications where an SCR or TRIAC may be used, there are a few limited examples outside AC. But you can't 'neutralize' any votes, you'll need to make them better enough that people want to upvote them which might not be easy. As mentioned the real problem was likely the answers that got heavy downvotes so maybe you could try to expand a few answers to make them better as well.

Comment: Are moderators have some priviledge to delete that question as I don't think that editing a "closed" question make a sense of others.

Comment: @Atom, closed questions can be re-opened, in fact for a while they are called "on hold" so they appear on a reopen queue after being improved by an edit so many users can vote on if they should be reopened. Because yours are older they won't automatically appear, but anyone (with enough reputation or a moderator) that sees the edit can put a reopen vote on it if they feel the changes are sufficient to give it another go.

Comment: The only thing I have to add is that question bans are separate from answer bans.